# Instance of AggregateException causes TargetInvocationException

Tags: c#, winforms, resources, icons, targetinvocationexception

I have a problem that an instance of an `AggregateException` causes a `TargetInvocationException` after a couple of accesses to an Icon resource.

I broke down the problem to the following steps to reproduce (.Net 4.0 full or client profile):

- Create a new WinForms application (a console application will not work)
- Add an arbitrary icon (.ico file) to the resources
- Add the following code to the constructor:

  ```
  new AggregateException();
  for (var i = 0; ; ++i)
  {
    var icon = Resources.Certificate;
  }
  ```

You have to change the resource name to the name of your resource.

That's all. *Yes I know that this sample doesn't make sense. It's just to illustrate the problem. My working code is much more complex and all of this code is needed.*

Without creating this excection the application will work forewer. But if this exception is created the access to the resource will fail with a `TargetInvocationException`. The `InnerException` told me that the operation has been finished successfully(?!?!) having a two-line stack trace in System.Drawing.Icon (ctor + Initialize).

What can I do to prevent this problem?

**EDIT**
It seems to be a problem using Windows 7. A binary which fails on Win 7 will run correctly in Win 8.1.

Comment: Dispose icon?  Maybe memory is leaking?

Comment: ??? Did you try to reproduce the problem? Do you see any Disposes or memory leaking? The given code is all you need. Try it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the reason for that problem:

The following system configuration is needed to reproduce the issue:

- Windows 7 German Edition
- Microsoft .Net Framework 4.5.2 installed (yes I know my binary is compiled against .Net 4.0)
- KB2901983 installed

Having a machine which only contains the .Net Framework without KB2901983 the program works fine. After installing KB2901983 the program fails for the same binary (no recompilation required).

I tried to uninstall KB2901983 but it doesn't help. If it was once installed the program will fail. I tested it on a clean Windows 7 German Edition.